# DNS Name Server Changes are not picked from resolv.conf from my Web App running in Tomcat 7.0

Tags: java, tomcat, dns

My web application is running in Tomcat 7.0 and I have another application that comes and modified the Names Servers in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. I notice at times the changes are not picked up by my web application. When testing it out I put in fake DNS entries but my webapp was still able to resolve the hostname - This behavior was very random - At times it picked up the changes and at times it ignored the changes.

I was trying to look around but didn't see any documentation or reasoning behind this. Any insight would be useful.

Here are some more details which is similar to the one described in [this post](https://community.oracle.com/message/4652125#4652125)

**To reproduce**

1. Put a bogus DNS server into your /etc/resolv.conf
2. Start the test program. Wait for some time: it will trigger `UnknownHostException`s.
3. Fix the entry in /etc/resolv.conf,
4. Start Network Services
5. Test program will continue to trigger UnknownHostExceptions forever.

However a application running in Tomcat will exhibit a slightly different behavior - Most of the time the changes take effect but at times it does not

So for an application running in tomcat here is the scenario:

1. Put a bogus DNS server into your `/etc/resolv.conf`
2. Start the web application and try to get host from within the application - It will trigger  `UnknownHostExceptions`
3. Fix the entry in `/etc/resolv.conf`,
4. Start Network Services
5. The program will resolve correctly but at times it will throw `UnknownHostExceptions` or vice-versa.

I am really not sure what is the reason is for this flakiness and the difference in behaviors when calling `InetAddress` from a web application as against calling it from a standalone program. It has puzzled me for days now - any insight would be helpful along with a solution if possible

I am using the `InetAddress` class for all operations.

Comment: java uses it's own internal caching, which I've seen cause an uncountable amount of problems when it comes to DNS: http://www.techopsguys.com/2012/06/30/java-and-dns-caching/

Comment: The problem is not due to caching but changes in DNS servers. The Java application running in Tomcat exhibits weird behavior when there is a change in DNS servers in the /etc/resolv.conf file. Restarting web process seems to resolve the issue. I have updated my post with more details

Comment: Unless you have something like nscd caching locally on the box, I would expect that java is caching the negative response. If restarting tomcat generally fixes the issue and DNS itself is in a known good state, you can be almost guaranteed that it's a caching issue.

Comment: Not really Java caching. [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787534/are-the-changes-of-file-etc-resolv-conf-immediate) probably explains your problem system-wise, but the question remains how to trigger `res_init` in a running JVM.